# JQuery select2 multiple options to be selected via jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I have a select2 box with multiple property in rails i want to add an option in a to this box with a selected state when i call a particular javascript. How do I achieve this?

```
function handleAddSoftwareVersion(button){      
  $("#device_versions").append($('<option>', {
    value:1,        
    text: 'MyOption'
  }));
}
```

How do i add that selected property to the select box. I can get the select2 to show the value as an option but how do i make it selected?